# Java / Android-Studio - Accept All Permissions in One Click/Interaction

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I'm scott , programmer and passionate about cybersecurity, new in this community.

For the first time I had to create account here and post a question because I searched a lot but I don't found anything.
Everyone says that from android 6 or 7 is impossible to do that, but they are wrong!

I tell you why...

What I want to know is how to prompt to user to accept all permissions in a single click or interaction, and not accept one by one...

But they are wrong to say that this is not possible, because a clear example is the Meterpreter payload for Android, even running it in new versions of android asks for all permissions at once when you open the app.

This is an screenshot of how meterpreter's payload looks when it's run:

[Permission Request of Android APK Meterpreter Payload in Android modern versions][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wCJd.png

So.. Looking at that I think.. they are wrong, There is a way to do it, but the question is how.

I looked at the source code of meterpreter payload in github, but still i can't finde the part where ask the permissions, i looked at ALL files and any files says something about permissions, except manifiest.xml

I thought maybe it's possible to do something like when you click on a button "enable permissions" it opens the permission options of that application with  options all options checked or enabled(As seen in the picture above), then the user should only click once to accept all the permissions.

Anyone know how that is possible? How can i do that? Some hint ?

Any information would be greatly appreciated by me and anyone else looking for this at another time ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.